# Is it a good idea to run powershell on a server from a link on its website?

Tags: javascript, php, security, iis, powershell

I've helped write a script for my coworker which makes changes to the files and structure of the server, and now my coworker wants me to add a link to the website that will let him run the script from anywhere. This doesn't sound like a good idea to me, but I can't really give him enough details to talk him out of it.

Am I totally wrong in thinking it would be a bad idea to give access to this script on a web front?
If it's not a bad idea, where would you recommend I start with it? What sort of security measures should I be careful about?
If it is a bad idea, how would you go about talking him out of it? (He outranks me a bit, and my boss expects me to help him)

Comment: Who all has access to the page that will have this link? There should (rather, needs) to be some kind of authentication before running a server-side function IMO

Comment: Anyone with the url has access to the page he wants to put the link on

Comment: Is the site internal only or does it have actual outside users?

Comment: it's at a university. Mostly only students will see it, but I believe it can be accessed outside of our network

Comment: Then absolutely not. It's pretty much giving the public free access to run a server-command that only certain people should be using. Incorporate some kind of auth system around it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bad idea to me.

I think you be better off and get all the benefits if you set up PowerShell Web Access instead:

> Windows PowerShell® Web Access, first introduced in Windows Server®
>   2012, acts as a Windows PowerShell gateway, providing a web-based
>   Windows PowerShell console that is targeted at a remote computer. It
>   enables IT Pros to run Windows PowerShell commands and scripts from a
>   Windows PowerShell console in a web browser, with no Windows
>   PowerShell, remote management software, or browser plug-in
>   installation necessary on the client device. All that is required to
>   run the web-based Windows PowerShell console is a properly-configured
>   Windows PowerShell Web Access gateway, and a client device browser
>   that supports JavaScript® and accepts cookies.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831611.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just Know, that if the cmd is able to be seen client side, a user could easily modify the cmd and send bad commands back to the server. I would say it is generally not a good idea at all.

Just know, that even with validation the user by logging in and such, it is still an added risk. I would say to add a web method that calls, and then triggers the command to run, so that it cannot be modified, only activated.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, no it's not safe. Authentication is great, but also don't allow just any command to be run - Sanitize your inputs.

If this is part of a Windows Domain (which it probably is), he couldn't do much anyways - Things executed through IIS usually run as a local user without admin rights.

**Bottom line**

This is what Remote Desktop and **Powershell Remoting** was made for. If he has internal access, turn on Powershell Remoting. He can then run Powershell on that server from any other domain system with Powershell installed. Do not run shell or Powershell commands from IIS or Apache in general.